# Curve followed by M(x,y) such that <AMB = 30 or 60 or any other angle

Tags: curves, plane-geometry, angle

So imagine two point A and B.

If we draw a circle C with diameter AB, and have M be a point on this circle, then Angle AMB will always be 90

We can define C as the curve followed by M(x,y) such that Angle AMB = 90.
 C is then a circle.

But would the curve looks like if we define the angle AMB=30 or 40 or 120?

Would it be an ellipse? A hyperbola? A parabola? Something else?what?

I tried to use geogebra to trace M but I failed, if you can help on that also it would be great!

Comment: It is an arc. In Spanish it is called "arco capaz", but I don't know how to say it in English. The Wikipedia's page about it has no English version.

Comment: It would be a circular segment, delimited by AB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called major arc segment *of a circle* or minor arc segment *of a circle* depending on whether the angle included is acute or obtuse. They can be simply called minor or major arcs. A constant angle is contained in a circle as a geometric property.

[Arcs Major/Minor](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=662&q=arc%20circle%20&oq=arc%20circle%20&gs_l=img.3...2041.5621.0.7085.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.hmcntrc%2Ccfro%3D1%2Chm-qwp-shp-ido%3D1%2Chm-qwp-shp-hmbtialc%3D1%2Chm-qwp-shp-fpl%3D1...0...1.1.64.img..0.0.0.c8OfE-JMywI#imgrc=YPe6YpVxqqLkRM:)